# Looping colors percent to RGB

Tags: javascript, html, css, rgb

I want to change colors from number. In here, i use RGB colors and I want to change colors if my change number.

```js
function percentToRGB(mx,mi,md) {
var div = (mx-mi)/2; 
  var r, g, b;

    if (md < div) {
        // green to yellow
        g = Math.floor(255 * (md / div));
        r = 255;

    } else {
        // yellow to red
        g = 255;
        r = Math.floor(255 * ((div - md % div) / div));
    }
    b = 0;

    return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}


function render(mx,mi,i,x) {
    var x = 20;
    document.getElementById("divX").innerHTML=x;
    var res;
    
   if(i === x){
      document.getElementById("divX").style.backgroundColor=percentToRGB(mx,mi,x);      
   }    
}
function repeat(fn, times,z,y,x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      fn(z,y,i,x);
    }
  document.getElementById("divX").style.backgroundColor=res;
}


repeat(render, 100,10,20);
```

```css
li {
    font-size:8px;
    height:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divX"></div>
```

Example, i want to change number from 20 to 10 and yellow colors will change colors accordingly number. 
But in my code just show one colors (yellow).

Comment: You need to copy and paste you code here with your question also leave the fiddle link will be help full.

Comment: var res; is not define

Comment: @NisalEdu i remarked this code document.getElementById("divX").style.backgroundColor=res;

Comment: What is the question? What do you mean by "*gradient colors use percent*"? CSS `rgb()` func can also take percentages.

Comment: sorry, i made mistake and i want to change colors based on number. 
example, if i change number 10, the colors will change @Kaiido

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me... (consider [edit]  your question to make as clear as possible)

Comment: @Kaiido i changed my detail question. do you get it?